# angular factory multi http promis

Tags: angularjs

i need create a angular factory "MyConf" and i like call it all function in the controller like this MyConf.getListPays().

myConf factory must do multi http request but i like promis result when i write in controller MyConf.getListPays()

```
demretApp.factory('MyConf', function($rootScope, $resource, Demande, $q) {
    // initialisation

    var doInit = true;

    var myConf = {};

    var adresse = {};
    var listPays = {};
    var listNationalites = {};

    myConf.getAdresse = function() {

        if (doInit) {
            initDonneesCommunes();
        }

        return adresse;

    };

    myConf.getListPays = function() {

        if (doInit) {
            initDonneesCommunes();
        }

        return listPays;
    };

    myConf.getListNationalites = function() {

        if (doInit) {
            initDonneesCommunes();
        }

        return listNationalites;
    };

    var initDonneesCommunes = function() {

        // $rootScope.startSpin('spinner-demret');
        // Préparation des resources
        var adresseResource = $resource(cfg.urlDDRRest + 'adresse/' + Demande.getID());
        var dcPaysResource = $resource(cfg.urlDDRRest + 'dc/pays');
        var dcNatioResource = $resource(cfg.urlDDRRest + 'dc/nationalites');

        return $q.all([ adresseResource.get().$promise, dcPaysResource.query().$promise, dcNatioResource.query().$promise]).then(function(resultats) {
            // retour OK : 

            adresse = resultats[0];
            listPays = resultats[1];
            listNationalites = resultats[2];

        }, function(resultatsKO) {
            //  KO
        })['finally'](function() {
            //
            doInit = false;
        });

    }

    return myConf;
});
```

i need when i call the first time getAdresse or getListPays or getListNationalites  or when i init the factory i do all http for just the first time

but i need when i call my factory like this MyConf.getListPays() i get the list not like this MyConf.getListPays().then(function (){ ...}) ... because i use MyConf.getListPays() in _foreach(...)

thanks for help

Comment: It seems you're only initializing the data once, then you can synchronously access the data. Instead of making all the functions a promise, make the initialization a promise. Like `MyConf.then(function(myConf) {/*work here*/})`

Comment: try to use the $q.all(), with allows to load several requests and then execute when all requests returns

Comment: you can give me exemple, tks